# Loading effect does'nt work while calling a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I wrote the code to implement a loading effect. However, when I click the button, the loading effect doesn't work. But, if I remove the function, the loading effect works. It seems the function prevent loading effect while it is running. What is the problem?

```
 <template>
   <div v-loading="loading">
     <center><el-button @click="updateData">Click</el-button></center>
   </div>
 </template>


  data() {
    return {
      loading: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateData() {
       this.loading = true
       uploadData().then(response => {
         const data = response.data
         if (data.code === 200) {
            this.$message.warning({ message: 'OK', duration: 5000 })
         } else {
            this.$message.error({ message: data.msg, duration: 5000 })
         }
       })
       this.loading = false
    },
    ....
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `this.loading = false` right after your `uploadData()` method which is running async. Place the line inside your `then()` method as follows:

```
 <template>
   <div v-loading="loading">
     <center><el-button @click="updateData">Click</el-button></center>
   </div>
 </template>

  data() {
    return {
      loading: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateData() {
       this.loading = true
       uploadData().then(response => {
         const data = response.data
         if (data.code === 200) {
            this.$message.warning({ message: 'OK', duration: 5000 })
         } else {
            this.$message.error({ message: data.msg, duration: 5000 })
         }
         this.loading = false
       })
    },
    ....
  }
```